# Firebase functions how to access all children collections by one call?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Using firebase-admin, I have several collections inside one collection. I need them all, so I need to to 4 different calls. The first one for the "users" collection, and the other 3 are the children of "users":

```
  const profile = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(context.auth.uid)
    .get();

  const internProps = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(context.auth.uid)
    .collection("internProps")
    .get();

  const externProps = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(context.auth.uid)
    .collection("externProps")
    .get();

  const geoPath = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(context.auth.uid)
    .collection("geoPath")
    .get();
```

Making 4 calls to the DB sounds expensive.. Is it possible to somehow call only the "users" and extract the children collections from it? Or there is no other way than calling the other 3 methods :/

Comment: There are a couple of answers but I think the question needs clarity. It seems that the path `context.auth.uid` contains collections; `internProps`, `externProps` and `geoPath`. If you want to get ALL of the data in each of those collections, what's the point of separating them into discreet collections? e.g. if all of the data contained therein only applied to the doc `context.auth.uid` then why make them collections at all? Just store all of that data within the `context.auth.uid` doc? You're not running a query of anything so that would make it a snap to get it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow call only the "users" and extract the
> children collections from it?

It is not possible, with one query, to get documents from a parent collection and children collections of this parent collection.

The reason is that, from a technical perspective, a parent collection and the sub-collections of the documents in this parent collection **are not at all related to each other**.

Let's take an example: Imagine a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

These two documents (and the two immediate parent collections, i.e. `col1` and `subCol1`) just share a part of their path but nothing else.

So you'll need to issue four queries, one for each (sub-)collection.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for can't be done with firebase.

However, if your concern is number of calls that are being made, consider making using a **map** instead of a subcollection. This way you can get all data with a single request